# Mapped Network Drives performing slow on wifi

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp-sp3

i have a batch that starts three more files on a network drive and it takes approx. 12sec to open each one on wifi and about 5sec on LAN. Any help?

I run windows xp pro sp3

Comment: have you looked at / logged the dialog ? Likely the pause is due to authentication to the drives via the windows agent(s)

Answer (score 0):

First check if the shared location itself is slow to reach.

1. Check Wifi signal level
2. Ping the network locations - is there difference on wifi and LAN?